# How to do math with variables from different functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, var

Okey so i got two AJAX calls and inside them i got two variables i want to access so i can do some math with them and get the difference between them!

My code:

```
var flamingSkull = document.getElementById("flaming-skull");
var flamingSkullq = document.getElementById("flaming-skullq");
var flamingSkullSug = document.getElementById("flaming-skullsug");

  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=433850');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      renderFlamingSkull(ourData);
};

   ourRequest.send();


var ourRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest2.open('GET', 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetPriceList/v1/?appid=433850');
  ourRequest2.onload = function() {
     var ourData2 = JSON.parse(ourRequest2.responseText);
     renderFlamingSkullSug(ourData2);
};

   ourRequest2.send();



function renderFlamingSkullSug(data) {

   var sugString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ][today].price / 100;

   flamingSkullSug.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "$" + sugString);
}

function renderFlamingSkull(data) {

   var htmlString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].price / 100;
   var quantityString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].quantity;


   flamingSkull.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "$" + htmlString);
   flamingSkullq.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p>(" + quantityString + ")</p>");
}
```

I want to find the difference between 'sugString' and "htmlString" then i want to put it into my html code again like i did with 'sugString' and 'htmlString'. Anybody got a good answer for me on how i can do this? Thanks for your time! :)

I got this solution, but then i get this error: Cannot read property 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' of undefined

```
var flamingSkull = document.getElementById("flaming-skull");
var flamingSkullq = document.getElementById("flaming-skullq");
var flamingSkullSug = document.getElementById("flaming-skullsug");
var lowestPriceUrl = 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=433850';
var priceListUrl = 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetPriceList/v1/?appid=433850';

function makeRequest (method, url, done) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);
xhr.onload = function () {
done(null, xhr.response);
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
done(xhr.response);
};
xhr.send();
}


makeRequest('GET', lowestPriceUrl, function (err, res) {
   if (err) { throw err; }

makeRequest('GET', priceListUrl, function (err, res2) {
   if (err) { throw err; }

var sugString = res.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ][today].price / 100;
   var htmlString = res2.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].price / 100;
   var quantityString = res2.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].quantity;

flamingSkullSug.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "$" + sugString);
flamingSkull.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "$" + htmlString);
flamingSkullq.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p>(" + quantityString + ")</p>");

// Complete division
// ==================
// var division = Math.round(sugString/htmlString)
  });
 });
```

Comment: So you say that i just make the variables outside the function?

Comment: You could do this yes, I am going to write you a more complete answer right now

Comment: Okey thank you for you time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mere interest of making your variables available in a same context, you may declare them outside your functions - while keeping assigning to them in your functions. A simple outline of the solution would be:

```
var sugString;
var htmlString;
var quantityString;

function renderFlamingSkullSug(data) {

   sugString = ...

   ...
}

function renderFlamingSkull(data) {

   htmlString = ...
   quantityString = ...
    ...
}

// Execute your functions

// Then do some maths
```

In your case however, your functions are called asynchronously, so you woud need to put some extra mechanism in place to ensure both your callbacks have actually exectued before doing some math on the variables they assign to.

A simpler apprach in your particular case may be to just include your math logic inside the callback functions - and use a flag mechanism to decide whether you are ready to execute it.

```
var sugString;
var htmlString;
var quantityString;
var firstCallbackExecuted = false;

function renderFlamingSkullSug(data) {

   sugString = ...
   if (firstCallbackExecuted) {
       doSomeMathAndDomManipulation()
   }
   firstCallbackExecuted = true;
   ...
}

function renderFlamingSkull(data) {

   htmlString = ...
   quantityString = ...
   if (firstCallbackExecuted) {
       doSomeMathAndDomManipulation()
   }
   firstCallbackExecuted = true;
    ...
}

// Execute functions asynchronously

function doSomeMathAndDomManipulation(){...};
```

There is a bit of duplication in there and you could factor a little bit, but that is the general idea.

EDIT: the complete solution filling in the blanks would be as follows. As i point out in the comment, you'll still need to work out any other lingering issue your code may involve. I just filled in the gaps of the general solution outline with the code you have provided.

```
var sugString;
var htmlString;
var quantityString;
var firstCallbackExecuted = false;

var flamingSkull = document.getElementById("flaming-skull");
var flamingSkullq = document.getElementById("flaming-skullq");
var flamingSkullSug = document.getElementById("flaming-skullsug");

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=433850');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
            renderFlamingSkull(ourData);
        } else {
            console.log('Status is not 200');
        }
};

var ourRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest2.open('GET', 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetPriceList/v1/?appid=433850');
    ourRequest2.onload = function() {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            var ourData2 = JSON.parse(ourRequest2.responseText);
            renderFlamingSkullSug(ourData2);
        } else {
            console.log('Status is not 200');
        }
};

ourRequest.send();
ourRequest2.send();

function renderFlamingSkullSug(data) {

   var MostRecentDateAvailable = getMostRecentDate(data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ]);

   sugString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ][MostRecentDateAvailable].price / 100;

   manageMath();

   flamingSkullSug.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "$" + sugString);
}

function renderFlamingSkull(data) {

   htmlString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].price / 100;
   quantityString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ].quantity;

   manageMath();

   flamingSkull.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "$" + htmlString);
   flamingSkullq.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p>(" + quantityString + ")</p>");
}

function doSomeMathAndDomManipulation(){
    // This is where you put you math and dom logic
    // relying on the sugString, htmlString, and quantityString variables
}

function manageMath(){
    if (firstCallbackExecuted) {
       doSomeMathAndDomManipulation()
    }
    firstCallbackExecuted = true;
}

// Method for converting date object to "yyyy-mm-dd" string format
Date.prototype.custoFormat = function(){
  var day = format2Digits(date.getDate());
  var month = format2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
};        

// Helper function
function format2Digits(n){
  return n<10? '0'+n:''+n;
}

function getMostRecentDate(obj){
    var date = new Date();
    var tryNb = 10;

    while(!obj[date.custoFormat()]){
      if(tryNb === 10) {
        console.log("Too many tries");
        return false;
      }
      date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
      tryNb++;
    }

    return date.custoFormat();
}
```

Comment: Okey thank you, but what should i fill the .... with? And check the answer i post please, its another solution, but still i get an error

Comment: I added a complete solution base on your code originally provided. Note that you will still need to work out any other issue your original code may involve to make this work.

Comment: The response property doesn't exist in your data object. 

Check how the response returned by your callback function is actually formatted to understand how it will be parsed into JSON - and thus what properties will actually be available.

Comment: okey thank you very much! I think this will fix my problem now! But i still got an error on renderFlamingSkullSug: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at renderFlamingSkullSug (main.js:46)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest2.onload (main.js:38)

Comment: And im sorry for needing everything with a spoon, but this is my second project with javascript and ajax.. But again thank you very much for helping me out! Really aprecciate it! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Are you able to target the line causing the issue in your code? Can you paste it here - since you must have changed it in some way compared to original code

Comment: "renderFlamingSkullSug(ourData2);" And "sugString = data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ][today].price / 100;" maybe because something is wrong with the [today]? but that worked out well before..

Comment: Okey, i found the problem.. on the JSON file the last date there now is 2016-12-16 so is there a way that just pick the last date object? If you open the JSON file you understand what i mean :)

Comment: I've added some extra code with a second edit to my main response

Comment: now i got this "main.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ++" on the "try++;" line

Comment: Change it to tryNb++;

Comment: Done, now its one more thing, guess this is last. "Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined" at this line: while(!o[date.custoFormat()]){

Comment: and what should i use instead of "today" now? :)

Comment: I just removed the "o" and that fixed the first problem for me. Now its just to put what i need to put instead of today

Comment: Still "Uncaught ReferenceError: ubdateObject is not defined"

Comment: I got confused with another post, I'm sorry..  It's late.. And this post is long :) o is whatever you are calling the today property on, so data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ] I guess

Comment: Haha, no problem, im just grateful that you still help me! You are the best! So i changed "o" to "data.response[ 'Skin: Flaming Skull Face Bandana' ]" now, is that correct? Then i get the main.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: And i am really sorry that i have made this so long, i am just very bad at this and want to be better :) Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the complete solution. One of the api services you call here is currently unavailable which may explain why your data object is undefined.